# Tokens standards on go-ethereum and Quorum - ERC721

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum, erc-721, eip

Someone just told me that Quorum does not implement EIP721, so it does not support ERC721 tokens.

I always though token standards are just standards you should follow in your smart contract code and not something natively programmed in the core of Quorum or go-ethereum.

So is that assumption true ? can I use ERC721 token standard on Quorum ? if not, any idea about ways to create non-fungible assets on Quorum ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You'd have to ask the "someone" that told you that, but I don't see what Quorum could do to disallow ERC721. As you said, token standards are just standards you follow in your smart contract code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats incorrect. Any smart contract deployable to Ethereum is automatically compatible with Quorum, this includes ERC20, ERC721 and much much much more.